# Add profile image to bottom AppBarLayout(Android)

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

Sorry for my english. I try understand how i can add profile image(ImageView) to AppBarLayout like this:

[image]

I have display this layout in emulator like this:

[image]

Bellow my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ui.test.ScrollingActivity3">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.AppBarOverlay">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/asd"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:background="@color/colorBlack50"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp">

            <TextView
                android:text="asdasd"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </RelativeLayout>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling3" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/asd"
        app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
        app:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"
        android:src="@drawable/red_bg"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I try understand this AppBarLayout and do something what i want))

Comment: try this https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

Comment: @NileshRathod thanks but i need square imageView in the header